# Use a single ng-repeat to populate data in two different DIV's

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on an Angular project and I have an HTML template where I want to implement the functionalities.

**HTML** :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" ng-controller="getAllBenchersController">
        <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <div class="panel-heading dark-overlay">
                <svg class="glyph stroked clock">
                    <use xlink:href="#stroked-clock" />
                </svg> Talentpool
            </div>



            <div class="panel-body showdetails" style="display:none" >
                <div class="profile">
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right showback top" style="margin:0px 10px 10px 0px" title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="back to list"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></a>
                    <div style="margin-bottom:15px" class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                            <h2> {{employee.firstName}} </h2>
                            <p> <strong>Title:</strong> Web Designer / UI.</p>
                            <p>
                                <strong>Primary Skills :</strong> Read, out with friends, listen to music, draw and learn
                                new things.
                            </p>
                            <p> <strong class="mrs">Skills:</strong><span class="label label-green mrs">html5</span><span class="label label-green mrs">css3</span><span class="label label-green mrs">jquery</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="../../NewUI/img/user.png" alt="" style="display: inline-block" class="img-responsive img-circle">
                                <figcaption class="ratings">
                                    <p><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></a></p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-center divider">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 emphasis">
                            <h2> <strong>20,7K</strong></h2>
                            <p> <small>Followers</small> </p>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Follow </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 emphasis">
                            <h2> <strong>245</strong></h2>
                            <p> <small>Following</small> </p>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Profile </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 emphasis">
                            <h2> <strong>43</strong></h2>
                            <p> <small>Snippets</small> </p>
                            <div class="btn-group dropup">
                                <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Options </button>
                                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right text-left">
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>&nbsp; Send an email</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-list"></span>&nbsp; Add or remove from a list</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-warning"></span>&nbsp; Report this user for spam</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" role="button" class="btn disabled">Unfollow</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="panel-body showdetails1 showbackdetails" id="details">
                <!--<div class="pull-right">
                    <div class="btn-group" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-filter" data-target="available">Available</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-filter" data-target="billed">Billed</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-filter" data-target="reject">Reject</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-filter" data-target="all">All</button>
                    </div>
                </div>-->
                <div class="table-container" ng-repeat="employee in data">
                    <table class="table table-filter">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr data-status="available"  class="showbackdetails showdetails1">
                                <td>
                                    <div class="ckbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                                        <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="star"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> </a>
                                </td>
                                <td id="details">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <a href="#" class="pull-left"> <img src="../../NewUI/img/user.png" class="media-photo"> </a>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <span class="media-meta pull-right">dec 13, 2016</span>
                                            <h4 class="title "> {{employee.firstName}} <span class="pull-right available">(available)</span> </h4>
                                            <p class="summary">been moved to Talentpool...</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!--/.row--> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#details').click(function () {
            $('.showdetails').show();
            $('.showdetails1').css('display', 'none').hide();
    });
    $('.showback').click(function() {
             $('.showbackdetails').show();
            $('.showdetails').css('display', 'none').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

I am concerned about two divs in the code :

```
<div class="panel-body showdetails" style="display:none" >
```

and `<div class="panel-body showdetails1 showbackdetails" id="details">`

This `<div class="panel-body showdetails1 showbackdetails" id="details">`DIV contains a data table which populates data from a JSON endpoint using ng-repeat. The controller is assigned in a DIV outer to both the DIV's mentioned above. The first DIV `<div class="panel-body showdetails" style="display:none" >`is hidden by default.

On click of an element in the data table, the DIV will get hidden and the first DIV will be shown. The data table contains list of employees and the idea is to open up a div with the detailed employee information when the user clicks on the name of anyone of the employee.

This is done possible using Jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#details').click(function () {
            $('.showdetails').show();
            $('.showdetails1').css('display', 'none').hide();
    });
    $('.showback').click(function() {
             $('.showbackdetails').show();
            $('.showdetails').css('display', 'none').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Now the problem is that when I assign the ng-repeat to the outer DIV, the profile DIV is not opening up. I need the ng-repeat to loop through both the DIV's as the data for showing the list of the employees and the employee detailed information is coming from a single endpoint controller.

**Controller** :

```
myApp.controller('getAllBenchersController', ['$scope', 'dashboardServices', 'dataTable', '$window', '$timeout', '$filter', function ($scope, dashboardServices, dataTable, $window, $timeout, $filter) {
    dashboardServices.getAllBenchers().then(function (result) {
      var mainData = result.data;
        $scope.showSkills = {};
        //Calculate Experience
        $scope.CalDate = function (date1, date2) {
            var diff = Math.floor(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
            var secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
            var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
            var hours = Math.floor(mins / 60);
            var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
            var months = Math.floor(days / 31);
            var years = Math.floor(months / 12);
            months = Math.floor(months % 12);
            days = Math.floor(days % 31);
            hours = Math.floor(hours % 24);
            mins = Math.floor(mins % 60);
            secs = Math.floor(secs % 60);
            var message = "";
            if (days <= 0) {
                //message += secs + " sec ";
                //message += mins + " min ";
                message = "Since today";
            } else {
                if (years > 0) {
                    message += years + " years ";
                }
                if (months > 0 || years > 0) {
                    message += months + " months ";
                }
                message += days + " days";
            }
            return message
        };


        $scope.getExp = function (date) {
            date = new Date($filter('date')(date, "yyyy/MM/dd"));
            var currdate = new Date($filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy/MM/dd"));

            var exp = $scope.CalDate(currdate, date);
            return exp;
        }

        //Calculate Experience end
        employeeTalentPoolServices.getAllBlocked().then(function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                mainData.push(result.data[i]);

            }
            $scope.data = mainData;
        });
        $scope.account = [];
        $scope.employeeAccount = null;
        $scope.showhide = true;
        //$scope.testFilter = function (item) {
        //    return (item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'available' || item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'blocked');
        //}
        $scope.blockEmployee = function (id) {

            employeeTalentPoolServices.blockEmployee(id);
            $scope.showhide = false;
        }
        if (!result.data.error) {
            dataTable.render($scope, '', "talentPoolList", result.data);
        }
    });



    employeeTalentPoolServices.getCustomerAccounts().then(function (result) {
        $scope.accountData = result.data;
    });

}]);
```

**Service** :

```
myApp.factory('dashboardServices', ['apiServices', function (apiServices) {

    var factoryDefinitions = {
        getTodaysStats: function (state) {

            return apiServices.getFromIndecomm('/WorkflowEntity?status=' + state).success(function (data) { return data; });
        },
        getRecentNews: function () {
            return apiServices.getFromTalentPool('').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                return data;
            });
        },
        getLastFiveBenchers: function (status) {

            return apiServices.getFromTalentPool('/EmployeeState?state=' + status + '&pageNumber=1&pageSize=5').success(function (data) { return data; });
        },
        getAllBenchers: function () {
            return apiServices.getFromTalentPool('/EmployeeState?state=Available&pageNumber=0&pageSize=0').success(function (data) { return data; });
        }
    }

    return factoryDefinitions;
}
]);
```

Please help me out with this. I want a solution to make this possible.

Comment: `ng-show` and `ng-hide` are used to show/hide html elements in angular templates

Comment: Okay, but if I use that, will it enable me to use the ng-repeat over two div's? That is my main concern since I already enabled the hide and show using jQuery

Comment: Far too much html here for a [mcve] , all that is needed is basic structure that should be easy to scan and not require scrolling

Comment: https://hastebin.com/awixusasob.xml : This might help